# Avoid unnecessary Keycloak sessions for basic auth

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

Our Java application provides both a REST and a SOAP webservice. The application is secured via Keycloak and Spring Security. We configured the Java Keycloak adapter to enable basic auth and set it to bearer only. Furthermore, we set the session strategy for Spring Security to stateless and made sure that the session authentication strategy *NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy* is used.

On application side everything seems to work fine. No sessions are stored and other applications can use basic auth.

However, the client in Keycloak (which is used to authenticate the users) is filled with sessions. As we are performing a lot of calls against our applications, this leads quickly to several thousand sessions. The access type of the client in Keycloak is set to "public".

How can we make sure that the sessions are immediately removed after the REST/SOAP calls?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Keycloak user mailing list, this is currently not solvable. Something like "transient" sessions will probably be available in the future.